# asp.net core mvc view not found when starting via reflections

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, system.reflection

I am using an asp.net core mvc application based on .NET 4.7.
When I start generated sample Application, all works well.

But I have a bigger application with plugin support and I want to use asp.net mvc as one of my plugins.

The plugins are embedded loading the Assembly from the dll file and call a Start() method for starting the plugin.

When I add the asp.net start code in this Method, the web app starts by on any request I get this error:

```html
Connection id "0HLJE77KODDC8", Request id "0HLJE77KODDC8:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

But I know that the Index.cshtml exists.

I start asp.net app with

```
 CreateWebHostBuilder(new string[] { }).UseContentRoot(myWebBinPath).Build().Run();
```

from the Method called via reflection.
All dll reference assembleis are resolved well but do I have to set an additional path when I call the CreateWebHostBuilder from an other application context (e.g. Environemt CurrentDirectory ...)

I don't know where the framework looks for this views, so I cant adjust the file path...

please help me :)

Comment: Can you confirm that there is no `Index.cshtml` inside the folders that the error outputs? (`Views/Home/Index.cshtml` | `/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml` | `/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml`). Please show us the controller with the `Index` method.

Comment: @Matthijs: The Controller itself is not the problem, when I start the Application as standalone the index page is showing well.
I think asp.net use AppDomain BasePath for resolve views and in my example the AppDomain BasePath is pointing to an complete othe path as asp.net wants to....

Comment: Could you show us the value of `myWebBinPath`?

Comment: Its the path to my asp.net bin directory: D:\....\HomeDataManagement.Plugin.Service.Web\bin\Debug\net451

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

ASP.NET want a valid AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory path to asp.net bin directory.

So I have to create a new AppDomain for speceific parts of my app.

In my test scenario it works when I force update AppBase Path:

```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APPBASE", @"D:\...\HomeDataManagement.Plugin.Service.Web\bin\Debug\net461\");
```

Then the app environment is the same as running the exe file standalone, so I can call WebBuilder without contentRoot path:

```
    CreateWebHostBuilder(new string[] { }).Build().Run();
```